# Python XML Parsing can't find children of children

Tags: python, xml, rest, vcloud-director-rest-api

I'm trying to parse XML returned as a string from a http get request. I need to get a specific link inside the XML structure but for some reason I can't get to the link I need.
I tried `**enumerating**` the XML and printing **`child.attrib`** but the link I need is not displaying.

I need to find an element that is a child of a child and the element is called Vm, then I need to get the .attrib of that element.

Thus, I did some more research and tried finding the XML I needed by node name

The XML structure is:

```
<vapp>
   <link></link>
   <othertags></othertags>
   <Children>
      <Vm href='link I need'>
      <other tag options>
      </other tag options>
      </vm>
   </Children>
</vapp>
```

python code:

```
for i, child in enumerate(vappXML):
   if 'href' in child.attrib and 'name' in child.attrib:
      vapp_url =  child.attrib['href']

      r=requests.get(vapp_url, headers = new_headers)
      vmlinkXML = fromstring(r.content)

      for VM in vmlinkXML.findall('Children'):
         print VM

      for i, child in enumerate(vmlinkXML):
         if 'vm-' in child:
            print child.attrib

         if 'href' in child.attrib:
            vm_url =  child.attrib['href']
            if 'vm-' in vm_url:
               print vm_url
```

I can't get to the url no matter how I try. I only get the main child of vApp it never parses the  tag, or rather my code never goes further than the first child of the vapp and I don't know why.

I guess I wasn't clear. I'm parsing vCloud Director Rest API XML that is returned as a string. The first level is the vApp link which is essentially a container for VMs. I need to get the VM link under each vApp. The first one will select vApp links and query them.

Once it does a get request on the vApp link it gets the next level of XML data which is the structure I put above. so it passes the initial XML statement and returns vApp information.

Even when I print out every child.attrib fom vmlinkXML the link with vm doesnt get printed. however, If I just print r.content the link is there. Its almost like the XML parser doesn't see the  tag.

**I'm using Pythons XML.etree**

```
from lxml import etree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML, fromstring, tostring
```

**So to be clear the structure is:**

to get the vApp Links /api/admin/extension/vapps/query
then the returned information will contain links to each vapp in vCloud.
then I call the vApp link
https://vcloud.test.co/api/vApp/vapp-3b4980e7-c5ab-4462-9cfe-abc6292c15748
and it will return a structure similar to this:

```
<vapp>
   <link></link>
   <othertags></othertags>
   <Children>
      <Vm href='link I need'>
      <other tag options>
      </other tag options>
      </vm>
   </Children>
</vapp>
```

Tag contains the next level of link I need to query. However the XML parser with child.attrib never outputs anything under the  tag.

Comment: `if 'href' in child.attrib and 'name' in child.attrib:` - none of the top level tags have either of these attributes (much less both of them). You never make it past here.

Comment: Which xml parser are you using? An xpath expression such as `Children/Vm/@href` may give you what you want.

Comment: @tdelaney  Added some more clarity for you

Answer (score 1):

Solved***

```
r=requests.get(url + '/api/admin/extension/vapps/query', headers = new_headers)
vappXML = fromstring(r.content)
for i, child in enumerate(vappXML):
   if 'href' in child.attrib and 'name' in child.attrib:
      vapp_url =  child.attrib['href']

      r=requests.get(vapp_url, headers = new_headers)
      DOMTree = parseString(r.content)
      vmElements = DOMTree.documentElement      
      VMS = vmElements.getElementsByTagName("Vm")

      for vm in VMS:
         if vm.hasAttribute("href"):
            vm_link = vm.getAttribute("href")
            print vm_link
```